# Controlling Access To IDirect3DDevice9

Tags: c++, directx

So I am writing a resource manager for my in house game engine and am stuck on something.  Well, not really stuck but I feel like there should be a better way to do this.  The issue is: I have a resource manager class that consists of an LRU, a hash table (for quick resource look up), and another hash table that contains resource controllers(dictates how various files load and how to destroy different resources).

For the rendering part I have encapsulated the actual IDirect3DDevice object in a renderer class that sits in a SceneManager class.  The scene manager determines which objects are actually visible, etc through use of an OctTree and then renders them using the renderer object.

The problem is that, say the resource controller for a .jpg file to be loaded as a texture, needs access to the device.  This means I have to give the controller a pointer to the renderer which then needs to have a function that returns the texture created by the device.  However, that gives too much functionality to the renderer, theoretically it shouldn't care about anything but drawing.  This happens because, upon creation of a texture, you either have to call the devices member function or pass the device into one of the D3DX texture functions.  The same problem exists for other resources such as meshes because they need access to the renderer to create vertex and index buffers.

In addition, once the resource controller has access to the renderer, it could potentially call any of the draw functions if so inclined which is totally unnecessary.  Anyone have any work arounds to a problem like this, or is the inherent nature just a result of Microsoft giving to much functionality to the device object for D3D9?

Comment: Care to elaborate?  I've never heard of a game without resource management.  Some do it through a collective of different classes, but for smaller engines like mine a single class should suffice.

Comment: I think resource management is essential, too. Don't know whats the point of Puppys comment. For our inhouse engine all resources have direct access to the device. If you don't want this, you could write a delegator class, which gains the pointer to the renderer upon creation, but only publishes method for resource loading. Your resource classes get this delegator and so only have access to the needed methods.

Comment: Thanks!  I decided to give the resource controllers direct access to the device through means of a deviceready event.  This event is only fired off once on initialization which means no one can be sneaky and grab the device at some other point during runtime.